# What is the correct way to select a label with react-native-testing-library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, testing, jestjs

I am using tcomb forms to create my react-native forms. Within the form structure there are 3 dropdown selectors: birthdate, gender, and country. I am testing the component using jest and I cannot find a way to select the dropdown form sections. Currently I am trying this:

```
const firstNameInput = getByLabelText('First Name');
const lastNameInput = getByLabelText('Last Name');
const birthDateInput = getByLabelText('Date of Birth');
const genderInput = getByLabelText('Gender');
const countryInput = getByLabelText('Country');
const bioInput = getByLabelText('Bio');
const zipInput = getByLabelText('Zip');
```

This does not find any instance of the label, even though I have the label set as such:

```
  const Birthdate = t.refinement(t.Date, (d: Date) => isValidBirthdate(d));
const Name = t.refinement(t.String, (n: string) => isValidName(n));
const ZipCode = t.refinement(t.String, (z: string) => isValidZipCode(z));
const AboutYouStruct = t.struct({
  birthdate: Birthdate,
  gender: t.enums.of(
    Object.values(genders).map(g => g!.value),
    'gender'
  ),
  country: t.enums.of(
    countries.map(c => c.value),
    'country'
  ),
  firstName: Name,
  lastName: Name,
  zipCode: ZipCode,
  userBio: t.String
});

const FORM_OPTIONS = {
  stylesheet: Widgets.tCombStylesheet,
  fields: {
    firstName: {
      label: 'First Name',
      placeholder: '',
      error: Strings.invalidFirstNameWarning
    },
    lastName: {
      label: 'Last Name',
      placeholder: '',
      error: Strings.invalidLastNameWarning
    },
    birthdate: {
      mode: 'date',
      label: 'Date of Birth',
      error: Strings.invalidBirthDateWarning,
      config: {
        placeholder: ''
      }
    },
    gender: {
      label: 'Gender',
      error: Strings.invalidGenderWarning,
      config: {
        items: Object.values(genders),
        placeholder: 'Select a gender'
      }
    },
    country: {
      label: 'Country',
      error: Strings.invalidCountryWarning,
      config: {
        items: countries,
        placeholder: 'Select a country'
      }
    },
    zipCode: {
      label: 'Zip',
      placeholder: '',
      error: Strings.invalidZipCodeWarning
    },
    userBio: {
      label: 'Bio',
      placeholder: '',
      error: Strings.emptyWarning,
      type: 'textarea',
      multiline: true,
      numberOfLines: 3,
      stylesheet: {
        ...Widgets.tCombStylesheet,
        textbox: {
          ...Widgets.tCombStylesheet.textbox,
          normal: {
            ...Widgets.tCombStylesheet.textbox.normal,
            height: Widgets.tCombStylesheet.textbox.normal.height * 3,
            textAlignVertical: 'top'
          },
          error: {
            ...Widgets.tCombStylesheet.textbox.error,
            height: Widgets.tCombStylesheet.textbox.error.height * 3,
            textAlignVertical: 'top'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Render form

```
    <Form
      ref={formRef}
      type={AboutYouStruct}
      value={form}
      onChange={(f: AboutYouEntity) => setForm(f)}
      options={formOptions}
    />
```

Form Component

```
import t from 'tcomb-form-native';

import DatePickerTemplate from './templates/DatePickerTemplate';
import SelectTemplate from './templates/SelectTemplate';

/**
 * Instantiate tcomb-form-native with custom templates
 */
const { Form } = t.form;
Form.templates.datepicker = DatePickerTemplate;
Form.templates.select = SelectTemplate;

export default Form;
```

Comment: Looks like it is failing to find fields that are are select fields with options. Can you provide the component code that is rendering the fields you can find in tests?

Comment: @DrewReese added above. Thanks for the help, yes that is what I have inferred from this, any form option that is a dropdown cannot be selected.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the *actual* react component rendering the field, i.e. takes a specific option and values and supposedly renders a label and input/select field.

Comment: @DrewReese It is above. Is it not the <Form /> component that renders the formOptions?   Maybe I am not understanding though.

Comment: `Form` is rendering the field components, yes, but the field components rendering *something* is what I'm asking about. Can we see how the field component that aren't working are composed? Sorry if I was unclear.

Comment: @DrewReese The components in the form are rendered from the formOptions above.

Comment: The form options is an object, not a component rendering anything. Can we just start with the `Form` component then? Can you update your question to include the `Form` component code, then we can see how it is consuming the options and rendering fields, from there we can trace into the field components?

Comment: @DrewReese I included the entire component above. I understand what you are saying, the form component is coming from the tcomb-native-form package. It is an imported package and not a local component.

Comment: Basic debugging, Jacob, remember, we've zero context unless you provide it. Trace from working code into what isn't working. Looks like `Form` is from `import Form from '../../../shared/form';` though. Can we see that component? If necessary we can trace all the way into the source code of that package as maybe it is a bug there.

Comment: @DrewReese added above...my bad.

Comment: It's ok, debugging code can be tricky, but the more you do it the easier it can become. Ah, ok, can you now include `SelectTemplate` since it seems the select fields were the ones with issue?

Comment: @DrewReese Thank you so much I found my problem in the SelectTemplate. It rendered a <text> tag instead of a label so i just added a test id and jest was able to find it!